# Perl CGI meta tag viewport

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm using Perl CGI and I'm looking for how to include in the header, the viewport meta, ie the following html line:

```
<meta name = "viewport"
     content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = yes">
```

The header of my script is as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use DBI;
use CGI qw (-any);
use Switch;
my $ cgi = new CGI;

print $ cgi-> header ("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
print $ cgi-> start_html (
  -title => 'List of new movies',
  -author => 'xxxxx@yahoo.fr',
  -lang => 'en',
  -meta => {copyleft => 'xxxxx@yahoo.fr'},
  -style => {-src => 'https://my-web-server.com/style.css'},

);
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't confuse the HTTP header with the HTML `<head>` section.

If you were going to use the CGI module's HTML generating methods, then you would do this in the same way as your `copyleft` meta element.

```
-meta => {
    copyleft => 'xxxxx@yahoo.fr', 
    viewport => 'width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes'
},
```

However **HTML Generation functions should no longer be used** (as per [the CGI.pm documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used)).

You could replace this code with [a template system](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives#CGI.pm-Using-Template-Toolkit).

For that matter, you should [avoid CGI entirely](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE) and use an [alternative](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives#CGI.pm-Using-Template-Toolkit) such as [PSGI](https://plackperl.org/).

Comment: I will upvote this, because you have a soft approach in telling people to not use CGI. Some other people (not talking about Dave), just come out very aggressively in suggesting not to use CGI. Sure, it has its weak points, but it is there in one of the big name softwares (Apache httpd) for some reason. And is used in other places as well like embedding. In my humble opinion, I think it is good for getting started, before graduating to FastCGI/PSGI, etc.

Comment: @AhmadBilal — CGI.pm is still terrible. If you want to use CGI then you should use something like CGI::PSGI so that you can write code which will work when you move to a different protocol.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this (and you need no additional module than your CGI one)

```
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print qq(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Yourwebsite.com</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<more html code here .....>
</body>
</html> );
```

If you are just beginning with perl/programming, I do not discourage you from using CGI (like others usually do) but I would request you to know its limitation properly, and use/not-use it accordingly.

Comment: He already has a good answer explaining how to do it using CGI.pm (which is what he wanted). Why add another answer making the (frankly, terrible) suggestion to put raw HTML into the Perl program? We've know what a bad idea that is for decades :-)

Comment: Please do explain, how is that way of putting HTML .. a 'bad idea' (or link to it). I don't think, he wanted what Quentin provided.

Comment: Besides, I think Quentin added to/modified his answer later on

Comment: To answer your points in reverse order. Firstly, you can see when an answer has been edited. Quentin's answer hasn't been edited since it was first posted. Secondly, I don't see why he wouldn't want what Quentin posted. He's clearly writing code using CGI.pm (and using the HTML generation functions). He wanted to add a "meta viewport" tag. Quentin's answer demonstrates how to do that using the HTML generation functions that he is already using.

Comment: And as for why it's a bad idea to put HTML into Perl code - well, I think it's pretty obvious if you think about it. HTML and Perl are completely different things. In many projects they will be edited by completely different people. It's bizarre to expect HTML experts to edit Perl code in order to change the look and feel of a page (and even if the same person was editing the Perl and the HTML, it still makes sense to separate them into different files to make it easier). These days HTML files can get very complicated and combining HTML with your Perl code is madness. Use a templating system.

Comment: It appeared to me, he might have needed what I provided. What appeared to you is your opinion. You could have just upvoted Quentin's answer and left it at that. No need to tell me not to add a answer. Why do I feel aggressive vibes coming from you?

Comment: Sometimes, people come here.. just trying to complete a class assignment, or are beginning to code in perl/cgi, so they can do with more elementary methods. Yes CGI is old and has its drawbacks (which I remarked upon) , but they might not be looking for template system every time.

Comment: Ever thought that .. what appears "bizarre", "obvious" and "madness" to you, might not be so in every situation for everyone out there!? Anyways, the guy got his answer (although he has not yet ticked the 'chosen answer'), so you should let it cool man.

Comment: I should let it cool? :-) Other than my first comment (and, now, this one) I've just been answering your questions. And to be clear: CGI programming is **always** the wrong approach (CGI deployment might be the right approach, but that's a different issue) and using a templating system is **always** better than putting raw HTML in Perl code.

Comment: Well, I did say.. I got a vibe only (looking at the wordings). I'm happy to know, that its all cool.

As for CGI, that is your opinion, and might be the major opinion. But you never know, when someone would come out with some big improvement similar to FastCGI (not taking the other approaches like PSGI/mojo/dancer).

Comment: And yes, thank you for the part where you answered my questions.

Comment: See, here's the thing about PSGI. It does **everything** that CGI does. But it is more powerful and more flexible. Write a program and deploy it as a CGI program? Sure PSGI can do that. Move that program to FCGI or `mod_perl`? Yep, you can do that without changing a line of code. Take the same code and make it a separate daemon running behind a proxy? Of course. And all the time, you do have access to better debugging and testing tools than plain CGI gives you. I can't think of a single circumstance where I would rather use CGI than PSGI. I should blog about this in detail at some point.